# iTask with android service in Delphi

Tags: android, delphi, service, firemonkey, access-violation

I developed an android application where there is a service working in the background that job is to send notification about all rendezvous of the day.
In the main Application onCreat even i created the service form :

```
Application.CreateForm(TTservice, Tservice);
```

and i created a Tswitchbutton to start the service and to stop it :

```
 if switchnotificationenable.IsChecked then
var
Fservice : TLocalServiceConnection;
    begin
      Fservice := TLocalServiceConnection.Create;
      Fservice.StartService('TheService');
    end;
```

and another code in the service's event OnstartCommande :

```
Result := TJService.JavaClass.START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
```

when debugging a violation Access pointed at the code:

```
Fservice.StartService('TheService');
```

the error normally means that what i'm calling doesn't exist i was able to access a timer that is on my service form, so i have no idea what can be the problem.

i hope you guys can help me find the solution.

i'm using Delphi XE10.2 tokyo with an sqlite database,

have a good day everyone !

**Update**

I found out that when i remove the file.jar of the service from the project the violation access error is gone but the service doesn't start.

**-----UPDATE-----**
after finding out that i cannot work with a TTimer to create my push notifications, I'm thinking about making a iTask implemented with a loop that check every 30seconds with sleep function if the system time is equal to the time given in the main application by the user

```
procedure TDM.AndroidServiceCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  ntf : Jnotification;
  today : Ttime;
  mynotification : Tnotification;
  notiftime : TTime;
  T : iTask;
  TheINIFIle : string;
  config : Tstringlist;

begin
// Loading the database path and the time given by the user in the main apps who are saved in A Ini file
  TheINIFILE := TPath.Combine(TPath.GetSharedDocumentsPath ,'NotificationParams.ini');
  if FileExists(TheINIFILE) then
  begin
    config := Tstringlist.Create;
    config.loadfromfile(TheINIFILE);
    notiftime := strtotime(config.Values['TimeNotification']);
    TimerConnection.Database := config.Values['DatabasePath'];
    TimerConnection.Connect;
    // creating the iTask and giving it code that create notifications everytime the system time is equal to the notification time
    if TimerCOnnection.Connected = true then
    begin
      T := TTask.Run(procedure
      begin
        while Checking = true do
        begin
          sleep(30000);
          today := time;
          with QueryForNotification do
          begin
            SQL.Clear;
            SQL.Add('select client.entreprise, RDV.date_ntf, RDV.date_rdv, Client.num_C from client, Rdv where client.num_c = rdv.num_c and rdv.Date_Ntf = date(''now'')');
            Open;
            First;
            while not eof do
            if sametext(fieldvalues['date_ntf'], FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd', now)) then
            begin
              MyNotification := TheNotifications.CreateNotification;
              try
               if sametext(formatdatetime('HH-MM',NotifTime),formatdatetime('HH-MM',today)) then
                 begin
                   MyNotification.AlertBody := 'Le RDV avec ' + FieldValues['entreprise'] + ' vous attend!' ;
                   TheNotifications.ScheduleNotification(MyNotification);
                 end;
              finally
                next;
                MyNotification.DisposeOf;
              end;
            end;
          end;
        end;
      end);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: What is the message of the stacktrace (if there is any, I'm not familiar with delphi)? What OS version are you testing it on?

Comment: It fail at loading the libservice.so
Chargement du module : libTheService.so. Contient des infos de débogage. Adresse de base : $9D25FD50. Processus CirtaIT.apk (11837)

Exception 'first chance' à $9D90210C. Classe d'exception EAccessViolation avec un message 'Violation d'accès à l'adresse 9D90210C, accès à l'adresse 0000001C en cours'. Processus CirtaIT.apk (11837)

and am testing on a Wiko Rainbow jam os version 5.1
SDK version : 26.0.1

Comment: Looks like the Access Violation is happening in the service. You need to be careful not to include anything that uses FMX units in it.

Comment: I'm actually using a Tnotification,TUniconnection,TUniquery and a TTimer components in service.
and in the Uses i have the following :
System.SysUtils,
System.Classes,
System.Android.Service,
AndroidApi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText,
Androidapi.JNI.Os, System.Notification, FMX.Types, MainU,
  Androidapi.Helpers, System.Android.ServiceApplication,
  Androidapi.JNI.App, Data.DB, MemDS, DBAccess, Uni,
  System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Graphics, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Dialogs, UniProvider,
  SQLiteUniProvider, System.Generics.Collections,
  System.SyncObjs;

Comment: @Amir there are some limits to what you can do in a Service. TTimers, for example, can't be used in a Service.

Comment: Have you tried to change TTask.Run to TThread.CreateAnonymousThread ?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your Answers but looks like the iTask isn't working when i close the app
Note that the service is working perfectly but i'm not receiving any notification when closing the Main APP
@TomaszAndrzejewski no i didn't i will try it thank you